# How to create background images for multiple screen sizes and densities

Tags: android

I'm currently working on an app that will run on different smartphones, and we have our background image that will appear on all of the activities of the app.

Currently, all parent layouts are ConstraintLayout, and the background images are set in an ImageView that covers the entire screen. However, on some screen sizes, setting the ImageView on `fitCenter` simply doesn't work because either:

1. The screen can be too wide and the sides have white bars.
2. The screen can be too narrow, and a portion of the left and right sides of the background image get cut.

I know I can run a different scaleType, but that runs the risk of screwing up the original aspect ratios of the background image.

Are there design rules for this?

I've looked [but I've only found this from Android Dev's site.](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes) It has most of the screen sizes noted down, but not the aspect ratio.

What's the best way to go about this?

Should we make one for the largest size in each screen density and just hope that the same screens in the same screen density range scale it properly? Or just one per dimension? Or just one per aspect ratio?

Comment: You can use Android Studio to resize an image for different screen size like mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

i usually using ConstraintLayout to maintain image ratio

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
                android:orientation="vertical"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_poster"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="3:4"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

with this as long as the image ratio is 3:4, it wouldn't cropped the actual image

Comment: And this keeps the image in view even if you change the screen sizes?